# How can I change html and css of built-in Identity (server hosted, non-Angular) pages for dotnet core Angular site?

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-identity, single-page-application

I have a dotnet core V3.1 SPA using Angular 8.2. It's self-hosted, meaning this single project starts MVC, which serves the Angular SPA, and the web services used by the Angular SPA.

It came with a working identity system out of the box, but the login and register pages and stylesheets bypass Angular and are returned from the MVC server itself somehow. I need to modify the look and feel of these pages, but I can't find the html/razor or css files in my project anywhere. What am I missing? They can't be hard-coded into the Microsoft dlls, can they? I don't see the actual controllers hosting these pages either.

So my question is, how can I alter the look and feel of these login and registration pages?

Comment: yes they are hard coded to dlls! but you can simply modify them, take a look at this
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: Thank you Elyas, that was exactly what I needed!